# Swift - How to detect one eye blink

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, core-image

I use CoreImage to detect eye blinking, it works fine except when I try to detect only one eye. Any ideas in how to detect eye contact flirting **by using CoreImage**?

```
if let faceImage = CIImage(image: target) {  
    let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
    let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)
    let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: faceImage, options: [CIDetectorSmile:true, CIDetectorEyeBlink: true])

     if !faces!.isEmpty {
         for face in faces as! [CIFaceFeature] {
             let leftEyeClosed = face.leftEyeClosed
             let rightEyeClosed = face.rightEyeClosed
             let blinking = face.rightEyeClosed && face.leftEyeClosed
             let isSmiling = face.hasSmile

             print("isSmiling \(isSmiling)")
             print("blinking \(blinking)")
             print("rightEyeClosed \(rightEyeClosed)")
             print("leftEyeClosed \(leftEyeClosed)\n\n")
         }
     } else {
         print("No faces found")
     }
}
```

`UPDATE`
The properties hasLeftEyePosition and hasRightEyePosition are always true.

> Both Eyes Closed

```
isSmiling false
blinking true
rightEyeClosed true
leftEyeClosed true
```

> Both Eyes Opened

```
isSmiling false
blinking false
rightEyeClosed false
leftEyeClosed false
```

> Left Eye Closed

```
isSmiling false
blinking false
rightEyeClosed false
leftEyeClosed false
```

> Right Eye Closed

```
isSmiling false
blinking false
rightEyeClosed false
leftEyeClosed false
```

Comment: What's the (expected and actual) output of your `print`s? What isn't working?

Comment: I've updated the question. By using CoreImage, unfortunately I can't catch a "eye flirting".

Comment: any updates? what did u do ?

Answer (score 0):

To enable or disable face tracking for the detector I had to set the **CIDetectorTracking** variable. It worked fine to catch eye blinking, but due to the slow performance in live videos I decided to implement it with ARKit.

```
let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorTracking: true] as [String : Any]
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cidetectortracking

Comment: For me, enabling this option does provide individual results for left and right eyes, however it becomes a lot more unstable when being able to detect both eyes open.